# Using FTP Connection with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, ftp

I keep some data on an FTP server.

Can I conect with ArcMap 10.1 to use this data?

Comment: You need to use Python to connect to a FTP site - see this question and accepted answer - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31567/how-to-copy-geodatabase-on-ftp-site-to-local-geodatabase-using-python

Comment: Copy - paste the code to Python Console or in Toolbox as a tool?

Comment: You can make a Python ToolBox and and the script - example http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_Python_toolbox/001500000022000000/

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can but it really wouldn't be recommended.
Here is a really [good post on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/6079/how-can-i-mount-an-ftp-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows) about mounting a FTP server connection as a local drive; you can then set this as a connection in ArcCatalog that you can use.
Be aware that when you open some datasources remotely that network/connection performance can be a severe impact on stability. If that connection crashes; you run the risk of having to clean-up the temp files.